# How to add sensors in Android wearable

Tags: java, android, sony-smartwatch

I need to use the smartwatch heartbeat sensor in Android app, however with the type_all command, only the acceleration sensor appears. How do I add sensors?

Answer (score 0):

look out at this [code](https://gist.github.com/mjohnsullivan/557c2f19ba177312b1d7), you will get all sensor events